# Unresolved External Symbols LNK 2019

Tags: c++, lnk2019

I keep getting an "lnk" error. Below is the .h file.

```
template < class T, class KF >
class HashTbl
{
public:
    HashTbl(int initTableSize);
    ~HashTbl();

void insert(const T &newDataItem) throw (bad_alloc);
bool remove(KF searchKey);
bool retrieve(KF searchKey, T &dataItem);
void clear();

bool isEmpty() const;
bool isFull() const;

void showStructure() const;

private:
    int tableSize;
    List<T> *dataTable;
};
```

And this is the .cpp file:

```
template < class T, class KF >
HashTbl<T, KF>::HashTbl(int initTableSize) : tableSize(initTableSize)
{
    dataTable = new List<T>[tableSize];
}

template < class T, class KF >
HashTbl<T, KF>:: ~HashTbl()
{
    delete[] dataTable;
}

template < class T, class KF >
void HashTbl<T, KF>::insert(const T &newDataItem) throw (bad_alloc)
{
    int index = 0;
    index = newDataItem.hash(newDataItem.getKey()) % tableSize;

    if (dataTable[index].isEmpty())
        dataTable[index].insert(newDataItem);
    else
    {
        dataTable[index].gotoBeginning();
        do
        {
            if (dataTable[index].getCursor().getKey() == newDataItem.getKey())
            {
                dataTable[index].replace(newDataItem);
                return;
            }
        } while (dataTable[index].gotoNext());

        dataTable[index].insert(newDataItem);
    }
}

template < class T, class KF >
bool HashTbl<T, KF>::remove(KF searchKey)
{
    T temp;
    int index = 0;
    index = temp.hash(searchKey) % tableSize;

    if (dataTable[index].isEmpty())
        return false;

    dataTable[index].gotoBeginning();
    do
    {
        if (dataTable[index].getCursor().getKey() == searchKey)
        {
            dataTable[index].remove();
            return true;
        }
    } while (dataTable[index].gotoNext());

    return false;
}

template < class T, class KF >
bool HashTbl<T, KF>::retrieve(KF searchKey, T &dataItem)
{
    // apply two hash functions:
    // convert string (searchkey) to integer
    // and use the remainder method (% tableSize) to get the index

    int index = 0;
    index = dataItem.hash(searchKey) % tableSize;

    if (dataTable[index].isEmpty())
        return false;

    dataTable[index].gotoBeginning();
    do
    {
        if (dataTable[index].getCursor().getKey() == searchKey)
        {
            dataItem = dataTable[index].getCursor();
            return true;
        }
    } while (dataTable[index].gotoNext());

    return false;
}

template < class T, class KF >
void HashTbl<T, KF>::clear()
{
    for (int i = 0; i<tableSize; i++)
    {
        dataTable[i].clear();
    }
}

template < class T, class KF >
bool HashTbl<T, KF>::isEmpty() const
{
    for (int i = 0; i<tableSize; i++)
    {
        if (dataTable[i].isEmpty())
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

template < class T, class KF >
bool HashTbl<T, KF>::isFull() const
{
    for (int i = 0; i<tableSize; i++)
    {
        if (dataTable[i].isFull())
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

template < class T, class KF >
void HashTbl<T, KF>::showStructure() const
{
    cout << "The Hash Table has the following entries" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i<tableSize; i++)
    {
        cout<<i<< ": ";
        if (dataTable[i].isEmpty())
            cout << "_";
        else
        {
            dataTable[i].gotoBeginning();
            do
            {
                cout<<dataTable[i].getCursor().getKey() << " ";
            } while (dataTable[i].gotoNext());
        }
        cout<<endl<<endl;
    }
}
```

I don't know what is wrong. I have looked over both files and can't see what is missing or what doesn't match. I have looked at a few posts from the past and they point to a mismatch in the declaration and function call and I just don't see it. Any help would be appreciated.

Errors:

LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall HashTbl,class std::allocator > >::HashTbl,class std::allocator > >(int)" (??0?$HashTbl@UPassword@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@@QAE@H@Z) referenced in function _main    1

LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall HashTbl,class std::allocator > >::~HashTbl,class std::allocator > >(void)" (??1?$HashTbl@UPassword@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main

LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall HashTbl,class std::allocator > >::insert(struct Password const &)" (?insert@?$HashTbl@UPassword@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@@QAEXABUPassword@@@Z) referenced in function _main

LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall HashTbl,class std::allocator > >::retrieve(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >,struct Password &)" (?retrieve@?$HashTbl@UPassword@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@@QAE_NV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AAUPassword@@@Z) referenced in function _main

LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall HashTbl,class std::allocator > >::isFull(void)const " (?isFull@?$HashTbl@UPassword@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@@QBE_NXZ) referenced in function _main

Comment: At least post the full error information.

Comment: Sorry, just updated the post with the error descriptions.

Comment: OK, then "duplicate" mark is valid. You didn't (and shouldn't, generally people put the implementation of templates in .h/.hpp) include that .cpp in the main.cpp, did you?

Comment: No I did not include it

Comment: Then anyway you need to include the template implementations in main.cpp.